# How to build multiple range sliders with Vue?

Tags: css, vue.js

To the creative problem solver out there and to the ones that experienced multi range sliders,

I am trying to built a tool where a user would be able to place items on a timeline in a specific order. Those items would have a range relative to time. The user could also stretch those items time range on the timeline.

To show what I mean I made this quick mock-up :
[image]

The object would look like this:

```
new Recipe = [
  { id: 1, timeStart: 6, timeEnd: 8},
  { id: 2, timeStart: 2, timeEnd: 6},
  { id: 3, timeStart: 18, timeEnd: 22}]
```

I have been able to drag and drop items of an array to rearrange them in a specific order before, but I have never seen any plugin where those items could be individual range sliders.

I know this would be really customized but I am trying to find some tips on how to get on with this. Thanks y'all.

Answer (score 0):

You said you have been able to drag and drop items in an array to change their order, and what you are describing should be no different.

In all cases where you are using drag and drop, you are really only dragging and dropping a data object.  It doesn't matter that the dropped data specifies a time range - that is only important to the rendering of the items in question, which you should encapsulate into some form of TimeRangeItem component.

Also, another way to solve this would be to have the data reflect the start time and a duration instead of the end time.  By doing this, drag and drop operations would not need to change the order of items in the array, as any item being dropped would merely be updating that items start time.

Comment: but they aren't just data objects. They are rendered into sliders. Like here: https://nightcatsama.github.io/vue-slider-component/#/basics/simple
And sliders are all on the same line. Also, drag and drop works with indexes if I am not wrong.